# Problem in rosnode

Tags: slam, navigation, rosnode, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rgbdslam package, I wrote a '--.cpp' file and built a node from that file. I often used to edited the cpp file and rebuilt the package. But later on I changed the name of the node to be built and deleted the old node manually (from the bin folder). Building the package was successful. When I run new node, and check it using

$ rosnode list

It shows the name of old node which I deleted and cannot find the name of the new node in the list.

When I tried,

$ rosnode info (name of the new node)

It reports as unknown node.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

And thanks in advance for your suggestions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45402/problem-in-rosnode/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A node's name is set by using the `__name:=my_node_name` parameter or, if the parameter is not specified by the name you pass in the call to ros::init. Note that roslaunch always wants a node name specified in launch files and uses the `__name` parameter internally.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-10-09**:
I mentioned the node name in cmakelists.txt as

rosbuild_add_executable(newnode src/new.cpp).

I run the node from $ rosrun pkg_name newnode.

The problem is I cannot find the newnode in the list of running nodes. When I tried info about the newnode it reports as unknown node.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-09**:
The binary name has nothing to do with the node name as it appears in `rosnode list`. As i said, it's only determined by the name passed to ros::init or the __name parameter.